# Ionic modal not showing

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

my ionic modal view will not show up.
The screen somehow will turn gray, but it doesn't show a modal.

I'm wondering what's wrong.

This is my code:
Orignial view:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-energized">
  <h1 class="title">Contact Info</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
  <div class="card" ng-controller='DashCtrl' ng-click="openModal()">
    <div class="item item-divider">
      {{contact.name}}
    </div>
    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
      {{contact.info}}
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Modal:

```
<script id="templates/contact-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <div class="modal">
    <ion-header-bar>
      <h1 class="title">Edit Contact</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Name</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="contact.name">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Info</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="contact.info">
        </label>
      </div>

      <button class="button button-full button-energized" ng-click="closeModal()">Done</button>
    </ion-content>
  </div>
</script>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {

    $scope.contact = {
      name: 'Mittens Cat',
      info: 'Tap anywhere on the card to open the modal'
    }

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/contact-modal.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.modal = modal
    })

    $scope.openModal = function() {
      $scope.modal.show()
    }

    $scope.closeModal = function() {
      $scope.modal.hide();
    };

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      $scope.modal.remove();
    });

  })
```

The window will turn gray, but there is no modal.

Thanks for help!

(Tried in Safari browser on Mac)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enclose your modal into `<ion-modal-view>` instead of `<div class="modal">`

```
<ion-modal-view >
    <ion-header-bar>
      <h1 class="title">Edit Contact</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
          <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Name</span>
              <input type="text" ng-model="contact.name">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Info</span>
              <input type="text" ng-model="contact.info">
            </label>
          </div>

          <button class="button button-full button-energized" ng-click="closeModal()">Done</button>
    </ion-content>
 </ion-modal-view>
```

[Documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/) for detail.

Comment: That code helped, thanks. But I think it's because it was wrapped in a <sript> tag, which is strange, because I've seen a few example on the net having the code wrapped in such a tag. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Not because of script tag, actually using div with modal class was old way of doing it(even i recently updated to latest way, which i told you), they could work with old ionic libraries, but not with latest ones. If you see documentation http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/ , they use <script> tag in example. And it is stated to use `<ion-modal-view >`, by the way i am glad it helped :)

Comment: I am having the same issue and the fix above doesn't work? It somehow works for a plunker but not for me.

Answer (score 3):

A small update:

In the current version (mine is 1.7.7) you have to use the wrapping `<ion-modal-view >`, but must not use the wrapping `<script>`-tag! Otherwise you will only get a dark overlay but not the modal-window!

Comment: I tried with and without script tag and it still doesn't work... BTW which version is 1.7.7 ionic?

Answer (score 0):

> without script tag,  its working in ionic version 1.3.0